# access machine using ssh with password

Tags: linux, debian, ssh

I want to introduce ssh authentication and I have configured the `ssh_config` file and disabled `passwordauthentication`. Now, im trying to access the machine using ssh but the access is denied! Is there any way to access the machine now using password?

Comment: A console login.

Comment: If you disabled password authentication in `sshd_config`, then you cannot authenticate with password when accessing via ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, put on your running shoes: You need to visit the machine in person, log in via console, and turn passwordauthentication back on.

If it's not a real box, you may need to mount a bootable ISO and use Rescue Mode.

Also, set yourself up with a pre-shared key (try "man ssh-copy-id") and enable these 3 lines in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, to give yourself a backup in the future:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then generate and copy over a RSA key. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and tell you  later the result